# Расчеты и визуализация данных Teradata

Tags: sql, база-данных, дерево, teradata

Здравствуйте. Есть огромная БД с позициями. На выходе нужно получить дерево со значениями разными вариантам группировки позиций (не суть). Расчеты очень тяжелые, буквально каждая позиция сравнивается с каждой по нескольку раз.

С помощью каких инструментов это можно реализовать? Где лучше проводить расчеты? Как визуализировать все это в виде дерева?

Была идея выгружать данные, заливать их в csv и считать с помощью php, но интуиция и знакомые подсказывают, что такими расчетами я нагну локальный сервер + сама согнусь, пока он досчитает. Позиция очень много.

Comment: Для начала придумать оптимальный способ сравнения. понять, действительно ли нужно сравнивать одно и то же "_по нескольку раз_". Потом посмотреть нельзя ли целиком удержать в ОЗУ все данные, если нет, придумать свою структуру хранения на диске, позволяющую поднять данные с него за наименьшее время. Подумать не помогут ли стандартные алгоритмы СУБД для решения задачи. Использовать предварительный расчет и кеширование

Comment: К сожалению, сравнивать так и так придется, так как эта алгоритм подсчета такой по установленной формуле. Идея проекта в том, чтобы пользователь подключил необходимую БД и уже само приложение проводило расчеты и вывело визуализированный в виде дерева итог группировки позиций.

Comment: Моя ошибка в неправильно заданном вопросе. Я спрашивала не про комп/дисковое пространство и т.д. А про средство для расчетов. Какой язык? Подсказали, что с Терадаты может приложение на питоне подтянуть данные, рассчитать и визуализировать. Есть ли еще какие-то инструменты?

Comment: так средство расчетов зависит от того, где эти расчеты будут происходить. тот же питон вы можете поставить у себя на сервере и считать соответственно на нем. значит тратите свои ресурсы + нужно перекачать все данные от пользователя к вам. А вот заставить пользователя поставить себе питон будет проблематично. Начнем все таки с того, как пользователь "подключает свою БД" и в каком виде предполагается визуализация - в виде Web-интерфейса или декстопного приложения или может в виде отдачи пользователю ексельки, с заложенными в нее графиками

Comment: Идея с веб-интерфейсом была отложена, сейчас ориентация на десктопное приложение. Интерпретатор Питона у пользователя стоит, расчеты происходят на машине пользователя.

Comment: С Teradata можно данные вытянуть куда угодно и каким угодно языком/инструментом обработать. У Teradata есть свои решения по постройке деревьев и тп. Можно написать UDF которая будет строить все что вам нужно. Современный бест практис это скорее затянуть данные в Hadoop и там запустить необходимый процесс. Все зависит от того какие компетенции есть и какими ресурсами располагаете.